# Can I resume fast sync in GoEthereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, fast-sync

I have synced whole geth into computer in --fast mode. However, it had to be stopped at one point today. Using the already downloaded data, can I pass the download phase and resume from where it is left?

If not, can I use the already downloaded data to speed up the sync?

Comment: state is automatically healed if you are using latest geth 1.10.8

Comment: yes you can, when you restart it, geth will pick up where it left off

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the current GoEthereum versions support *snap* sync by default. This is resumeable operation. You do not need to give extra command line parameters like `--fast` anymore to activate it.

[image: Snap sync]

My node synced under 8 hours using the default parameters.

[More information about snap sync and its speed](https://blog.ethereum.org/2021/03/03/geth-v1-10-0/).

[More information about runnning an Ethereum node yourself](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513).

Comment: how do you create a "snap sync"?