# Getting inconsistent responses with web3.eth

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ens

The code runs but says "food.eth" is available (it isn't):

```
var Web3 = require("web3")
let web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8546");
var ens = web3.eth.ens;
const words = [
    'beer',
    'food',
    'chovy',
];

(async () => {
    for (let word of words) {
        console.log('checking: '+ word);
        const addr = await getDomain(word);
        console.log(word+': '+ addr);
    }
})();

async function getDomain(word) {
    try {
        const addr = await ens.getAddress(`${word}.eth`)
        console.log(addr);
        return addr;
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
}
```

I'm running geth with the following command on Ubuntu 20.04:

`geth --syncmode "light" --ws --mainnet`

edit: From what I can tell after reading up, I need a "archive node" to query eth domains. Since the domain may not have been registered in the last 128 blocks (which is what a full node is).

Most of the cloud apis out there don't allow many queries for archive nodes.

edit: So apparently I have to set the resolver for the call to work:

```
const resolv = await getResolver(word);
await ens.setResolver(`${word}.eth`, resolv);

async function getResolver(word) {
    try {
        const resolv = await ens.getResolver(`${word}.eth`);
        console.log('found resolver: ', resolv._address);
        return resolv._address;
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err, 'resolver error');
        return;
    }
}
```

But now I get this error:

```
$ node index.js       
found resolver:  0x4976fb03C32e5B8cfe2b6cCB31c09Ba78EBaBa41
(node:426847) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options.
    at Object.ContractNoFromAddressDefinedError (/home/ubuntu/www/eth/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:125:16)
    at Object._executeMethod (/home/ubuntu/www/eth/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:772:48)
    at /home/ubuntu/www/eth/node_modules/web3-eth-ens/lib/contracts/Registry.js:461:109
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Comment: archival node takes 8TB of space

Comment: ENS queries are just contract Call()s , full node is fine

Comment: will a light node work or must it be full node?

Answer (score 0):

The geth light sync mode might not have the required state information to give you the right answer. Because it has not fetched the state that tells whether the name is registered, it defaults to unregistered.

Instead, do [a snap sync for your node](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/107794/620).

Comment: so add `--snap` to my `geth` command?

Comment: I only have 30gb space total...will light node not work for getting accurate results?

Comment: That is not going to work, because the size of Ethereum state is more than 30 gigabytes. You cannot query the state if it doesn't fit on your computer.

Comment: Just use an external free node API like CloudFlare: https://ethereumnodes.com/

Comment: what web socket address do I use?

Comment: how big is the eth blockchain?

Comment: You need around 200GB space.

Comment: its giving me wrong answers still. a full node requires 9tb of space and nobody has a cheap ssd for that much. Apparently eth won't run on hdd.

Comment: I do not believe the error `Error: No "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options.` is related to the the node, but it is related to your code. I suggest you open another question for it.

Comment: right, that's why i posted the code. smh